# Gravatar image not displaying although URI correct - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gravatar

I'm working through the Michael Hartl Rails Tutorial and I'm getting a weird problem with the 'adding a Gravatar' section. I've checked the code against another implementation of a Gravatar in Rails I did for a different tutorial and don't see what's different.

Basically: the image doesn't appear, but if you right click the space and visit the URL it directs to the correct Gravatar page.

Code: (show.html.erb)

```
<%= gravatar_for @user %>
```

Code: (users_helper.rb)

```
def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 50 })
    size = options[:size]
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatars/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=#{size}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
end
```

Totally stumped, know it's probably something really obvious that I'm missing, but from the book and the Gravatar website I seem to have gone about this right...

Comment: are you sure the url is right ? the urls I've seen have avatar (singular) in the url, not avatars.

Comment: whats the html code that gets rendered here?

Comment: @FrederickCheung can't believe it. Checked the link and it was correctly working - but only because Gravatar was automatically handling the incorrect URL. It should have been AVATAR singular as you say, feel like such a chump!

Answer (score 7):

The url is wrong

```
gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatars/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=#{size}"
```

correct version

```
gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=#{size}"
```

singular form ".../avatar/...."

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue which I resolved by whitelisting the Cloud9 page in Adblock and ghostery

Comment: I has a similar issue and had to whitelist the site on my "Disconnect" plugin in chrome and then the images loaded as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the whole users_helper.rb file?

Mine look like this:

```
module UsersHelper

  # Returns the Gravatar (http://gravatar.com/) for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

With the

> module UsersHelper

and an extra

> end

Comment: I omitted the module beginning and end since I figured they were implicit :)

Answer (score 0):

The same issue for me. I fixed it by changing gravatar_url to "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}", not https connection.